# Copy data from same table based on other columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named tableX structed like this. Notice the relation of childNo and parentNo columns.

```
childNo | parentNo |locationId |value
--------+----------+-----------+--------+
26      |    NULL  |   7       | value1 |
27      |    NULL  |   7       | value2 |
28      |    27    |   7       | value3 |
29      |    27    |   7       | value4 |
30      |    27    |   7       | value5 |
34      |    NULL  |   7       | value6 |
```

and I want to copy the same value column information to a different locationId(let's say locationId = 3) with new childNo and parentNo (protecting the relation)

Expected output.

```
childNo | parentNo |locationId |value
--------+----------+-----------+--------+
36      |    NULL  |   3       | value1 |
37      |    NULL  |   3       | value2 |
38      |    37    |   3       | value3 |
39      |    37    |   3       | value4 |
40      |    37    |   3       | value5 |
44      |    NULL  |   3       | value6 |
```

How can I achieve that using T-SQL?

Comment: childNo and parentNo dont have to increment by 10. It could be any number as long as the relation is protected.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but you could just do:

```
insert into t(childNo, parentNo, locationId, value)
    select t.childNo + 10, t.ParentNo + 10, 3, t.value
    from t
    where t.locationId = 7;
```

Comment: parentNo is sometimes NULL. Wouldn't t.ParentNo + 10 cause problem?

Comment: @nyilmaz . . . `NULL + 10` --> `NULL`.

Comment: This should work as long as the Identifiers (child / parent no) are not auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

I try this sample in SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @lastParent int;
DECLARE @lastChild int;
DECLARE @newLocationId int;

SET @newLocationId = 3;
SELECT @lastParent = MAX(ParentNo) FROM tableX WHERE ParentNo IS NOT NULL;
SELECT @lastChild = MAX(ChildNo) from tableX;

INSERT INTO tableX (childNo, parentNo , LocationId, valueColumn)
SELECT
    @lastChild + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LocationId ORDER BY childNo) AS childNo,
    CASE WHEN (ParentNo IS NOT NULL) then @lastParent + 1 
         ELSE ParentNo
         END as NewParentNo,
    @NewLocationId as NewLocationId, valueColumn 
FROM tableX 
WHERE LocationId = 7
ORDER BY childNo
```

Two instances of this code running at same time, can produce duplicates values. I think your table must have Unique constraint on childNo and some trigger to validate parentNo